# password_hash into MySQL database cutting off/out characters

Tags: php, mysql, php-password-hash

I've been having trouble with storing a password_hash into my MySql database. It's cutting off characters from the beginning and some in between.

I've tried setting the encoding to UTF 8 in the HTML, setting the same in the connect function and also I've changed the collation to every possible type. Yet I am able to paste the correct hash from an echo into the database and that works fine.

```
$password = $_POST['pno'];

$pno = password_hash($password,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);


MySqlDb::query('INSERT INTO user (name, email, pno, address_line_1, address_line_2, town, county, post_code, phone) VALUES (:name, :email, :pno, :address_line_1, :address_line_2, :town, :county, :post_code, :phone)',
            [':name'=>$name, ':email'=>$email, ':pno'=>$pno, ':address_line_1'=>$address_line_1, ':address_line_2'=>$address_line_2, ':town'=>$town, ':county'=>$county, ':post_code'=>$post_code, ':phone'=>$phone]); 

echo $pno;
```

So the echo will give me this: $2y$10$rtlUaDeXsyhtWS5.SS4nuu.xapBdrHXG7V.DpSLCLAAwYqXPJHKWi

But in the database it stores this:
y$rtlUaDeXsyhtWS5.SS4nuu.xapBdrHXG7V.DpSLCLAAwYqXPJHKWi

I've also tried the encode and decode functions, pretty much out of ideas.

```
class MySqlDb {

    /**
     * @var MySQLi instance
     */
    protected static $link;

    /**
     * @var bool set to true to print query before executing
     */
    public static $debug = false;

    /**
     * Creates a new MySQLi instance use getConnection() to retrieve
     * @return none
     */
    private function __construct() {

        self::$link = @mysqli_connect(DATABASE_HOST, DATABASE_USERNAME, DATABASE_PASSWORD, DATABASE_NAME);
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            //die('MySqlDb Error: Could not connect to database ('.mysqli_connect_errno().')');
            throw new Exception('MySqlDb::() Could not connect to database (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ')');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the MySQLi connection
     * @return MySQLi instance
     */
    public static function getConnection() {

        if (!self::$link) {
            new MySqlDb();
        }
        return self::$link;
    }

    /**
     * Helper function for mysqli_query if params are given will use quote function
     * see below MySqlDb:quote this is to help avoid sql injection attacks and automatically escape slashes etc
     * 
     * @param string $sql 
     * @param array $params
     * @return mysqli_query resource ...
     *
     * Example:
     * MySqlDb::query("drop from user where id=$_GET['id']"); // very bad 'id' could contain "' or 1=1" 
     * MySqlDb::query("drop from user where id=:id", [':id' => $_GET['id']]); // much better
     */
    public static function query($sql, array $params = null) {

        $con = self::getConnection();

        if (!empty($params)) {
            $sql = self::quote($sql, $params);
        }
        if (self::$debug) {
            echo $sql;
        }
        $res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        if (!$res) {
            //die('MySqlDb Error: query: '.mysqli_error($con));
            throw new Exception('MySqlDb::query() ' . mysqli_error($con));
        }
        return $res;
    }

    /**
     * Helper function to quote sql values similar to pdo::bindvalue using named parameters 
     * to help avoid sql injection attacks and avoid using stuff like addslashes
     *
     * @param string $sql sql string to quote
     * @param array $params key value pairs of parameters and values to placed into them
     * @return string sql quoted string
     *
     * Example:
     * $sql = MySqlDb::quote("select * from users where id=:unique1 or id=:unique2", [':unique1'=>2, ':unique2'=>4]) 
     * TODO:
     * MySqlDb::quote("select * from users where id+5 = :id or id = :id",[':id'=>3] fails on number params dont match like pdo
     * could convert 'substr_count($sql, ':')' into '$unique_sql_param_count' 
     * e.g. preg_match_all("/:[\w-_]+\b/i", $test, $matches); $paramcount = count(array_flip($matches[0]));    
     */
    public static function quote($sql, array $params) {

        // check correct number of params
        if (substr_count($sql, ':') != count($params)) {
            //die('MySqlDb Error: quote: number params do not match');
            throw new Exception('MySqlDb::quote() number params do not match');
        }
        $cnt = 0;
        foreach ($params as $param => $value) {
            //$sql = str_replace($param, "'".self::escape($value)."'", $sql, $cnt); // was matching sub strings :(
            $sql = preg_replace("/$param\b/i", "'" . self::escape($value) . "'", $sql, -1, $cnt);
            if ($cnt !== 1) {
                //die("MySqlDb Error: quote: param '{$param}' not matched or is duplicate");
                throw new Exception("MySqlDb::quote() param '{$param}' not matched or is duplicate");
            }
        }
        return $sql;
    }

    /**
     * Wrapper for mysqli_escape_string
     * @param mixed $value
     * @return escaped value
     */
    public static function escape($value) {
        return mysqli_escape_string(self::getConnection(), $value);
    }

    /**
     * Helper function to return all rows in result as an associative array
     * @param string $sql
     * @return array array of arrays
     */
    public static function all($sql, array $params = null) {
        return mysqli_fetch_all(self::query($sql, $params), MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    }

    /**
     * Helper function to return first row in result from potential multiple values
     * @param string $sql
     * @return array single array
     */
    public static function first($sql, array $params = null) {
        $res = mysqli_fetch_array(self::query($sql, $params), MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        return is_array($res) ? $res : [];
    }
    /**
     * Helper function to return first field in result from potential multiple values
     * @param string $sql
     * @return mixed single variable
     */
    public static function scalar($sql, array $params = null) {        
        $res = mysqli_fetch_array(self::query($sql, $params), MYSQLI_NUM);
        return is_array($res) ? $res[0] : null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you share the table scheme?

Comment: If you perform a raw database query in your application, does that work properly? We cannot guess what's behind `MySqlDb`

Comment: Maybe it's a coincidence, but it appears to be removing substrings with a specific pattern (a dollar sign followed by digits). I don't see anything in the code you posted that would indicate why that would be happening, though.

Comment: What is the data type of the `pno` column?

Comment: As stated by @Nico Haase you have some weird things inside the `MySqlDb::query` method...

Comment: Seems like the DB class may be broken. My guess is that it is replacing $1, $2, etc with nothing. Can you link to the mysqldb class?

Comment: pno is text type colummn. It was Char. I thought I would try both, and I had set the Char length to something like 232 originally. I'll put the code above for the MySQL classes

Comment: @ChrisHudson `varchar(255)` is recommended in http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: @ChrisHudson Please enable the debug flag in your `MySqlDb` class. What is the SQL statement which is generated by your method?

Comment: Why are you (badly) reinventing prepared statements when you're already using a database adapter perfectly capable of proper prepared statements?!

Answer (score 2):

This line in your `quote` method is the direct cause of the problem.

```
$sql = preg_replace("/$param\b/i", "'" . self::escape($value) . "'", $sql, -1, $cnt);
```

The result of `self::escape($value)` will be your original hash,

```
$2y$10$rtlUaDeXsyhtWS5.SS4nuu.xapBdrHXG7V.DpSLCLAAwYqXPJHKWi
```

In the context of `preg_replace`, the `$2` and `$10` are meaningful. In [the Parameters section of the `preg_replace` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php#refsect1-function.preg-replace-parameters) it says

> **replacement** may contain references of the form \n or $n, with the latter form being the preferred one. Every such reference will be replaced by the text captured by the n'th parenthesized pattern.

You have no parenthesized patterns, so those values are replaced with nothing.

---

You could fix it by escaping any `$` in the replacement parameter, but I would rather recommend replacing your escape/replace-based `quote` method with a method that creates a prepared statement and binds the parameters before executing it.